# VBA API for SAP BO Analysis for Excel

Tags: vba, business-objects, sap-analysis-for-office

I haven't found many articles on this yet on Stack Overflow so I will elaborate a bit more by giving the necessary background info.

I'm using the **SAP BO Analysis for Excel add-in** through which I'm retrieving data in Excel from SAP BW.

The Analysis add-in comes with a GUI through which you can **enter variables in the query** (so called **prompts**).

It additionally has an VBA API so you can set the variables through VBA.

My big problem is that ***the setting of variables through VBA only seems to work when I have set at least 1 prompt through the GUI*** :S

Below is my full VBA code. It's inspired on http://precisionstudio.net/uploads/3/0/5/0/3050843/sap_instructorhandbook.pdf & http://scn.sap.com/community/businessobjects-analysis-ms-office/blog/2011/06/26/can-you-use-vba-with-businessobjects-analysis-find-out-here

**The Dims lResul, lResult & lResultt return 0**, but when I manually fill in a value in the GUI prompt and re-run the VBA macro, it works (returns 1)... it fills in the other values. Very strange.

Has somebody encountered same issues and know the way out?

```
Private Sub EnableAnalysisOffice()
    Dim addin As COMAddIn
 
    For Each addin In Application.COMAddIns
        If addin.progID = "SBOP.AdvancedAnalysis.Addin.1" Then
            If addin.Connect = False Then addin.Connect = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call EnableAnalysisOffice
    Call MyGetData
End Sub
 
Public Sub MyGetData()
    Dim Iret As Long
    Dim lResul As Long
    Dim lResult As Long
    Dim lResultt As Long
 
    Iret = Application.Run("SAPLogon", "DS_1", "200", "myUser", "myPassword")
    MsgBox (Iret)
    Call Application.Run("SAPSetRefreshBehaviour", "Off")
    Call Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "PauseVariableSubmit", "On")
    'Select data based on WBS
    'lResul = Application.Run("SAPSetVariable", "0S_WBSE", Worksheets("Prompt Values").Range("A2").Value, "INPUT_STRING", "DS_1")
    'MsgBox (lResul)

    'Select data based on Employees
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPSetVariable", "YEMPLSEL", Worksheets("Prompt Values").Range("A5").Value, "INPUT_STRING", "DS_1")
    MsgBox (lResult)
    
    'Document Date
    lResultt = Application.Run("SAPSetVariable", "YDOCUMENT_DATE", ">=01\-01\-2015", "INPUT_STRING", "DS_1")
    MsgBox (lResultt)
    
    Call Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "PauseVariableSubmit", "Off")
    Call Application.Run("SAPSetRefreshBehaviour", "On")
    'Call Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh")
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't every Excel-Add in created by commercial software packages come with a documentation of how to use it and what its limits are (specially that you are using SAP)?

Comment: After you run the GUI manually once, does the VBA always work until you quit Excel? If so, maybe some part of the add-in (library,etc) doesn't get loaded by calling `addin.Connect = True`

Comment: I have found a solution in the meantime, not really a nice one. I save the current prompts within the workbook & refresh with those prompts. After that, i allows me to modify the prompts. Just sharing in case somebody encounters the same problem...

Comment: I recommend raising a ticket/incident about this with SAP, they can consider it and either fix it or take it in as an enhancement request for a future release.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late to answer...
I read a article called "Best Practices for VBA in SAP BI Analysis for MS Excel". (I didn't link it since I don't know if it's allowed or not).

Basically, it said that we should refresh before using SAPSetVariable.
I added following code before SAPSetVariable, and it worked for me.

```
lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_1")

If lResult = False Then
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh", "DS_1")
End If
```